# How to run a Dart callback dispatcher from Linux/Windows code in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Flutter Engine has a `DartExecutor` class, written in Java. It allows, for example, run a Dart callback from native Android code. Is there a similar way for Linux/Windows/macOS? I'm trying to organize a WorkManager-like behavior to run the callback in a separate main Isolate. This allows to run Flutter code inside this callback, unlike the usual Isolate.

`fl_project` allows to set custom Dart entry point arguments (then pass `fl_project` to `fl_engine` and run it), but I haven't found a way to replace the Dart entry point, while the internal API has this option https://engine.chinmaygarde.com/struct_flutter_project_args.html#aa7aab3cb3dc28d379b97adef882f52e4

Comment: It's similar to MethodChannel, but it's a slightly different mechanism.